# Read in of a specific amount of variables

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have to read in different coordinates and save them into a struct. For this task I can only use

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

and `scanf` to read it in. Also I have to use the a GCC compiler.
For one struct I need 4 coordinates, so the insert can look like this:

```
Coordinates: 11 12 13 14 21 22 23 24
//           | First   |  | Second |
```

For the read in I have the following structure:

```
int read() {
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
```

Main:

```
printf("Coordinates: ");
int buffer = read();
while(buffer != 0) {
    //write current buffer in struct
    ...
    buffer = read();
}
```

So the problem is, with this structure the insert needs to end with `0`. But my task is, that the read in procedure ends when there are no more "foursome pack" of coordinates.
For example:

```
Coordinates: 11 12 13 14 21 22 23 24 31
//            | First  |  | Second |  invalid -> while loop ends
```

So I dont know how to cancel the while loop, because I dont know how much coordinates the user will feed in.

Permissible library functionalities: `scanf(), printf(), putchar()`.

I hope somebody of you understand me and can help me.

Comment: I think having a function called `read` is not a good idea. Perhaps it is used elsewhere - http://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Comment: Read the entire line in as a string.  Then parse it

Comment: Do all valid lines start with `"Coordinates:"`?

Comment: How can I save it as a string? And no, the `Coordinates: ` is the output of `printf()` in the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code fails to distinguish between read a `"0"` and encountering an error.  It does not keep track of reading how many of the 4 numbers read.  It does not detect the prefix `"Coordinates:"`

```
int read() {
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}
```

---

Read in a "fourpack", 1 fourpack at a time.

```
struct pt4 {
  int i[4];
};

// Return EOF, 0, 1, or 4
struct pt *Read_foursome(struct pt4 *fourpack, int count) {
  // Look for prefix
  if (count == 0) {
    // Record number of characters read
    int n = 0;
    if (scanf(" Coordinates:%n", &n) == EOF) return EOF;
    if (n == 0) return 1; // Unexpected data, prefix not exactly there.
  }
  // record the number of fields successful scanned.
  int n = scanf("%d%d%d%d", 
      &fourpack.i[0], &fourpack.i[1], &fourpack.i[2], &fourpack.i[3]);

  // No more data
  if (n == EOF) return EOF;  

  // no numeric  data
  if (n == 0) return 0;

  // Unexpected data
  if (n != 4) return 1;

  // As expected
  return 4;
}
```

Sample usage

```
int n;
int count = 0;  
struct pt4 fourpack;
printf("Coordinates:"); 
while ((n = Read_foursome(&fourpack, count)) == 4) {
  // Use fourpack
  printf(" %d %d %d %d", 
      fourpack.i[0], fourpack.i[1], fourpack.i[2], fourpack.i[3]);
  count++;
}
printf("\n"); 

// If n == 0 maybe time to look for another line of fourpack
// If n == 1, some syntax error in the line.
```

Comment: Hmm it looks like `== EOF` doesnt work =? ... but also the thing is, that I dont know how many fourpacks the user will insert. Also it have to read in the coordinates in one line until the user hit return.

Comment: @Coli "doesnt work" conveys little information.  Express what is expected and what happens.  "have to read in the coordinates in one line until the user hit return" is a new requirement best appended to the post. IAC, the above answer "works" as you need, yet the sample usage is not a "give me the code answer".  Some work remains on your part.

Answer (score -1):

Check the return value of `scanf`. It returns how many items it read. If it returns `1` then it read an integer. If it returns `0` then it didn't (due to end-of-file or to bad input).

```
int read() {
    int a;
    if (scanf("%d",&a) < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Beware that with this function it is impossible to distinguish between EOF and the user typing `0`. Both will cause `read()` to return 0. If `0` is a legitimate input value then you should come up with another way to indicate an error to the caller.

Comment: What happens if the person types in 0 - a perfect value? (you cannot tell an error from a valid response)

Comment: @EdHeal - He's talking about the return value of the function, not the value stored in the variable.  If the user enters 0, then the return value will be 1 and the value of `a` will be zero.

Comment: Think of the case that `scanf` reads 0. This is a valid integer - so what return statement has been used - the error case or the successful one?

Comment: "If it returns 0 then it didn't read anything." - This is not true

Answer (score -2):

If you follow this pseudo code, it should work:

1. Get all the input from the user until you don't want more input (whatever that case maybe) is entered and store in an int array.
2. Go through the array in multiples of 4 (use mod), if you have multiples of 4 store it in a struct.
3. If not a multiple of 4, this means you have exhausted the array and there are no more "foursome pack" of coordinates.

So basically you will have two while loops (easier). One loop will just keep storing the numbers in an array until you don't want more input (whatever that case maybe) has been entered. And the other while loop will go through the array in multiples of 4.

Comment: Why does people hate zero?

Comment: Before I thought that when the user enters 0, it should stop propmting for more, that is why I edited it and said: "(or what ever you want to be an end case to be)". Well, I understand what you are saying, I will remove the 0. =p

Comment: "whatever that case maybe" the thing is, that I dont know how many coordinates the user will insert...

Comment: Ok, then go until EOF. that should be fine.